# Sonarqube 5.0 with powerbuilder

Tags: sonarqube, powerbuilder

Iam using sonarqube 5.0.1 to configure java,.net languages of our company projects I have a simple question whether sonarqube 5.0.1 or any latest version supports the analysis for power builder V12 or lower. Kindly give your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no.  However, this may be something Appeon Corporation (who is negotiating a licence with SAP to take over the development of PowerBuilder) may be interested in in the future.